# Rails :has_many explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Trying to understand the effects of `:has_many` as its introduced in the Agile Web Development book 4th Edition

The following relationship is set up for the cart

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

this compliments the associated `LineItem` class

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

All is fine, I fully understand the relationship modelling, and just trying to accept that it just 'works'. However, in code the author, instead of using the `LineItem.find` method to do a search on the underlying table, uses a `line_items` object, e.g.

```
current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first
```

Can someone please explain this, and ultimately I imagine, what the effect of the `:has_many` method call actually is? What is the `line_items` object, where does it come from? I guess the same question will apply to the effect of the other relational Rails methods.

Thanks.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider my answer just as a very big comment to *Chris Kimpton's* answer.

First, you should read the [API documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), where the associations are explained pretty nicely.

In short, when you call the method `has_many` in the code of a class *(remember that in Ruby every line is an executed code, so the `has_many :something` is just a call to some existing method)* then that method defines another two methods with the same name as the argument you have passed.

In this case that would be the Symbol `:line_items`, so the `has_many` method makes something roughly equivalent to : `def line_items(force_reload = false)` and `def line_items=(objects)`.

The newly created method `line_items` returns a collection object of all the LineItem objects filtered by `WHERE cart_id = #{self.id}` *(this is a simplified example)*.

That collection object works like an Array, but it also responds to some more methods *(like `find` or `build`)* helping you to manage the relation between the Cart object and LineItem.

So, the line:

```
line_items.where(:product_id => some_id).first
```

is the equivalent of:

```
LineItem.where(:cart_id => self.id).where(:product_id => some_id).first
```

Using the first method *(the `line_items` collection)* you do not need to remember about adding that `:cart_id => self.id` to every statement.

Comment: Ah, that explains it, wasn't getting anywhere with the docs. Really appreciate the time you take to explain

Answer (score 1):

If the code is exactly as you have written here, that line_items object must have been set up somehwere else in that code.

The has_many relationship will add a helper method to give the list of associated elements so it could be doing something like this:

```
cart = Cart.find(1)
line_items = cart.line_items
```

cart.line_items will return an array of line_items where `line_item.cart_id = cart.id`

Answer (score 1):

I presume that sample line of code is in a method of the Cart class?

One of the "features" of ActiveRecord / has_many call is to add this pseudo method to your class.

So the Cart class gains a line_items method to access them.

The line_items.where call is searching within the related line_items - not all LineItems, which is what your call would do.  It seems to be looking for a line_item related to a specific product - I wonder where the product_id var comes from - method parameter?

On the other side, the belongs_to call on LineItem adds a "cart" method to access the Cart it is in.

Hope this helps,
Chris

Comment: And the [API documentation of has_many](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) may be worth reading. It shows you more methods you can call on that `line_items` object.

Comment: Chris, good help thanks you the line_items object was created from a $ rails generate scaffold line_item product_id:integer cart_id:integer, which also created the LineItem base class. Thanks for helping, Paul.